# JSON error in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use the AFNetworking library to send a post request to an URL like this:

https://m.com/api/2.0/basic/sim_balance.json

That expects a username and password in the URL that are my parameters (as NSDictionary).

The URL gives a JSON back like this:

```
{
    "valid_until": "2011-05-05 22:13:28",
    "sms": 0,
    "sms_super_on_net_max": 300,
    "voice_super_on_net": 0,
    "credits": "0.00",
    "bundles": [],
    "is_expired": true,
    "sms_super_on_net": 0,
    "voice_super_on_net_max": 3600,
    "data": 0
}
```

This is my request function:

```
 +(void) request:(NSString *)endpoint : (NSDictionary *) parameters
    {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager POST:endpoint parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    }
```

I always get this as error:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x904b7e0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I validated the JSON and the server is sending valid JSON.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Do you ever set the `requestSerializer` property of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instance?

Comment: No, do I need to do this?

Comment: In your failure block, try inspecting the raw content of the response using `operation.responseString` or `operation.responseData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to ester. Also you need to set the basic auth headers right.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"Tom" password:@"test"];
[manager GET:endpoint parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {       
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response data: %@",operation.responseData);      
    NSLog(@"Response String: %@",operation.responseString);     
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to serialize the request body as JSON, you need to set the value of its `requestSerializer`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:....];
```

If you do not set the requestSerializer property, then the manager object will use [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) serialization by default.

Note however that AFHTTPRequestOperationManager will handle JSON in the *response* body by default.

Comment: I've added this. But if it happens by default why do I need to set this?

Comment: Oh, you're saying that the username/password can be sent in the URL of the request, so the server isn't expecting JSON in the request body. I misread your question. I think you can disregard this answer.

Comment: The server is expecting a username an password in the body of the post.

Comment: ok. So did setting the requestSerializer to AFJSONRequestSerializer fix the error?

Comment: I can't test right now the website is on maintenance. I will let you know when he is back up. I hope this fixed the problem.

Comment: To answer your question "if it happens by default why do I need to set this", the *request* is *not* encoded as JSON by default because the default value of requestSerializer is an instance of AFHTTPRequestSerializer rather than AFJSONRequestSerializer.